# MySql: insert decimal values (distortion)

Tags: mysql

[image]
Could you help me understand how to insert decimal data into the table.

My code:

```
INSERT INTO 
                  wp_ved_currencies (date, char_code, name, nominal, value)
                VALUES('2019/11/25', 'USD', 'US dollar', 1, 31.0902);
```

The problem is that decimal values are distorted:

[image: es (]

Comment: That is because your MySQL settings are incorrect. A properly configured MySQL server will abort the INSERT statement with an "out of range" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DECIMAL(20,20)` means that your decimal number can have maximum 20 digits all of which are on the right side of the decimal point. 20 digits in total - 20 digits after the decimal leave 0 digits for the left side.
The maximum number which can be stored in this column is `0.99999999999999999999`

Use two different numbers for precision and scale. For example `DECIMAL(10,4)` which would have the maximum allowed number to be `999999.9999`

The number you tried to store overflowed the maximum possible value and so the maximum was stored in the column.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different value for precision and scale

```
  value decimal(20, 8)
```

this mean  20 digit with 8 digit after the decimal separator

or for you data sample   31.0902

```
  value decimal(6, 4)
```

Comment: I have tried. Not working. The result has become 9.9999.

Comment: seems weird ..  check better  .. could be you have configured  comma for decimal  separator .. try insert  31,0902

Answer (score 0):

Please use **DOUBLE(6,4)** datatype for value column.
Thanks